# Playing web games that require arrow keys without using a physical keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I would like to play some web games like [Unikong](https://unikong.github.io) using my tablet. But the problem is, they require a keyboard, or specifically, the arrow keys in order to play.

I know I can connect a mouse and/or keyboard via OTG and play, but I don't always have access to them.

I have Hacker's keyboard (has arrow keys) but the game registers my arrow key inputs only sometimes at irregular intervals. This happens not only for Unikong, but other similar games too (I remember creating a small JS canvas game myself that it works fine on the PC, but not with hacker's keyboards' arrow keys). Here is a GIF from where you can see the problem (Sorry for the low quality 5 FPS GIF):

[image: Screenshot showing problem]

Note that this happens on some games only. For example, this problem does not exist with Chrome's T-Rex game.

So, how do I play web games that require the use of arrow keys using my Android tablet without a physical keyboard?

I'm running a rooted Android KitKat 4.4.2

Comment: [Game Pad](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fishstix.gameboard&hl=en) seems to meet your needs looking at the play store video ( I don't play games so not sure if that's what you want)

Comment: @beeshyams Unfortunately, for some reason, Game Pad's permanent notification doesn't work. I can't see any notification even though I've enabled its 'Permanent Notification' setting. So, I can't open the keyboard to test it.